# interior of a nested increasing union over a sequence of sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What are the weakest hypotheses on a topological space $X$ so that for every increasing sequence $S_n$ of subsets of $X$ we have that $\cup _{i=1}^\infty (S_n^o)=(\cup _{i=1}^\infty S_n)^o$

Comment: Seems false in general.  Consider an uncountable set with the smallest topology.

Comment: Hm I got it if $X$ is compact regular.  If there's more to be added, please go ahead, but with this, I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is false in the case of the compact regular space $X=[0,1]$, the closed unit interval with the usual topology. Let $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n,\dots$ be an enumeration of the rational points of $X$. Let $S_0$ be the set of all irrational points of $X$. For each $n\in\mathcal N$, let $S_n=S_0\cup\{r_1,\dots,r_n\}$. Then $S_0,S_1,\dots$ is an increasing sequence of sets whose union is the whole space $X$. Each $S_n$ has empty interior, so the union of the interiors is the empty set, but the interior of the union is the whole space.

More generally, the proposition is false in every T$_1$-space which has a countable subset which is not closed. (More generally still, it's false if there are countably many pairwise disjoint closed sets whose union is not closed.) On the other hand, it's true in a discrete space or a finite space.

A [*P-space*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297691/a-question-on-p-space) is a topological space in which countable intersections of open sets are open. (Some writers include some separation axiom in the definition.) Discrete spaces and finite spaces are trivial examples of P-spaces. Does every P-space have the property that, for any decreasing sequence of subsets, the interior of the intersection is equal to the intersection of the interiors?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is compact regular, then here is a proof.  I will prove the equivalent, complementary claim, which is that if $S_n$ are decreasing nested, then $\cap \overline{S_n}=\overline{\cap S_n}$.  Clearly we have right is contained in left.  If $x \notin \overline{\cap S_n}$ then by regularity I can find $U, V$ with $x\in U$ and $\overline{\cap S_n} \subset V$ with $U, V$ disjoint.  Consider the cover $V, \{\overline{S_n}^c\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  This has a finite subcover, and by nestedness we know therefore that a cover of the form $\overline{S_N}^c, V$ is possible for some $N$.  So then $\overline{S_N} \subset V$.  But then $x$ is not in $V$, hence not in $\overline{S_N}$ hence not in $\cap \overline{S_n}$.

Edit: This is mistaken, but I'd like to keep it up for future reference.